# Jenkins failover strategy

Tags: jenkins, master-slave

I would like to setup the jenkins build farm in such a way that the fail over of all nodes are handled including the master. I am not able to find an answer for the question "what if master node goes down?".

I need a hot-hot setup where in if one node goes down the other should be able to pick up the queue and when both are up, they should process the jobs exclusively. Can we setup two nodes where each node is master and slave to each other? Does that create a serious conflict?

I am new to Jenkins distributed build setup and your help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the CloudBees Jenkins Enterprise product http://jenkins-enterprise.cloudbees.com/docs/user-guide-bundle/ha-sect-failover.html which is able to deal with a master failure. That is a commercial product but if High Availability is a requirement then it could be worth the price.

Comment: Thanks.. I wish it was built within the core, may be in the future, or no!